# Center align content using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styles

My content page is something like this. I am using bootstrap 3.0.2. I want my table to be shown in the horizontal middle of the page (like some left margin of 250 px). Any class for this in bootstrap or any other layout helps? My table is very small of 3 columns and 5 rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table-condensed ">
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table-condensed center-block" style="width:100px;">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Maksym, but I want width auto

Comment: Change `style="width:100px"` to `style="width: initial; display: table;"` and you will get it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. Just out of curious any built-in bootstrap class have display type table?

Comment: Shanadas, I do not know.